Persistent "Qt platform plugin 'xcb' not found" Error in PyInstaller Bundled App on RK3568 SoC
I am developing an application for an ARM64-based embedded terminal using Python and OpenCV, bundled with PyInstaller. Despite successful compilation and deployment, the application fails to start on the embedded machine, presenting the following error:
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/tmp/_MEIxxxxx/cv2/qt/plugins"
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

The application is compiled in a Docker container on a Mac M1, same ARM64 architecture. Here's what I have tried:

Setting the QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH both within the Python script and through PyInstaller flags.
Explicitly adding all Qt-related libraries using PyInstaller’s --add-binary for each dependency found via ldd on libqxcb.so.
Ensuring all paths are correct and that the necessary files are included in the bundle, confirmed through pyi-archive_viewer.
Despite these efforts, the application fails to find the xcb plugin upon launch. Here are the details of my PyInstaller command:

pyinstaller --clean --onefile --hidden-import="PIL._tkinter_finder" \
--add-data "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms:./platforms" \
my_app.py


I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue, thank you!

Check your package includes libraries in .../lib/python3.6/site-packages/opencv_python.libs.

I ended up solving this problem by not using anymore the --onefile directive in PyInstaller. The monolithic output executable generation was getting broken for this library, maybe also for some others... As soon as I started generating a full directory of executable + libraries, it worked fine, with the cost of having to .tar.gz everything to distribute to the target platform, one more step on every compilation during testing phase...
